# addition of data into database from two diff models

Tags: python, mysql, django

My models.py is

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        ..........

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        ........

    def books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self)
```

I need to perform insertion of data into database from two different models. I need views.py sample, because I am using code which is not working properly. Please help me with this. I am using Django.I am using author as fireign key so that should set automatically,that is also not happenning

Comment: you again, what do you really need?

Comment: Explain to us further what you need so that we can understand. Don't create another same question again.

Comment: i want to add data(enter data) into database using a function in views.py.since  i am using two tables not able to add(update) the data into table from temples using POST method.need views.py for the above models.py file for adding the data like book_name,author_name & so on to table.Plz help me i am beginer to this framework in a company in training period so plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add_author(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        lname = request.POST.get('lname')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        age = request.POST.get('age')

        author = Author(
            first_name = fname,
            last_name = lname,
            email=email,
            age=age
            )
        new_author = author.save()

        book = request.POST.get('book')
        publisher = request.POST.get('publisher')

        fullname = "{0} {1}".format(new_author.first_name, 
                                    new_author.last_name)

        Book.objects.create(
            book_name=book, 
            author_name=fullname, 
            publisher_name=publisher
            author = new_author
            )

    return render(request, 'add_author.html')
```

**add_author.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h5>Author Info: </h5>
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
    Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br/>

    <h5>Book Info: </h5>
    Name: <input type="text" name="book"><br/>
    Publisher: <input type="text" name="publisher"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: can you plz provide me a code without using form,bz my pm given that it should be done without using form.my actual requirement is to insert the data into two different tables.

Comment: the answer given was working fine but the data in class book is not getting updated.how to perform that plz

Comment: Because I didn't put book input yet

Comment: hi in this foreign key (author is not incrementing automatically).And can you plz guide me how to edit and save the already existing data from i.e row in a table from the database

Comment: you must create new question for that and I already answer your question for this